# sde for brownian bridge

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations, brownian-bridge

Let $B(t)$ be a standard Brownian motion and
\begin{align*}
Y(t)=B(t)-tB(1) &&
Z(t) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 Z(t)=(1-t)B\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right)& t\in [0,1)\\
0 & t=1 \\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}
with $Y(0)=Z(0)=Y(1)=Z(1)=0$
two Brownian bridges. Its easy to see, that $Z(t)$ satisfies the sde $dZ(t)=-\frac{Z(t)}{1-t}dt+dB_t$. \
Is there also a sde satisfied by $Y(t)$?

Comment: You are using the Brownian motion $B$ three times but they are not the same: $Y(t)$ is $\sigma(B_s;0\le s\le\color{red}{1})$-measurable. How about $Z(t)$? and how about the $Z(t)$ defined by that SDE? Morale: when you deal with Brownian bridges you have to define the BM that generates it carefully. [George Lowther](https://almostsuremath.com/2021/03/29/brownian-bridges/) goes to the bottom of this. Once the correct BM for $Y$ is found it satisfies the same SDE as $Z\,.$

Comment: see here too https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4314118/filtration-enlargement-and-brownian-bridge-sde

Answer (score 1):

First to be clear the representation

$$b_{t}=B_{t}-tB_{1}$$

is not Markov with respect to the usual Brownian filtration (since it requires evaluating in the future at $t=1$) and so it will **not** satisfy an SDE process with strong solution.

The way around this is to use a different filtration.

We observe that $b_{t}=B_{t}-tB_{1}$ is independent of $B_{1}$ because indeed
$$E[B_{1}b_{t}]=t-t=0,$$

for $t\leq 1$. In particular, the conditioned process $(B_{t})_{t\in [0,1]}|B_{1}=0$ is equal in law to $b_{t}=B_{t}-tB_{1}$. So one candidate filtration is

$$\mathcal{F}_{t}^{brig}:=\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}\mathcal{F}_{t+\epsilon}^{B}\vee \sigma(B_{1}), t\in [0,1].$$

In [Brownian Bridges](https://almostsuremath.com/2021/03/29/brownian-bridges/) they describe this situation in detail.

> Thm: A continuous process $\{B_t\}_{t\in[0,T]}$ is a Brownian bridge if and only if $B_0=0$ (almost surely) and it is Markov (with respect to its natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_{\cdot} $) such that for all $0\le s < t\le T$ then, conditional on $\mathcal{F}_s, B_t$ is normally distributed with mean and variance given by,
> \begin{aligned} &{\mathbb E}[B_t\;\vert \mathcal F_s]=\frac{T-t}{T-s}B_s,\\ &{\rm Var}(B_t\;\vert \mathcal F_s)=\frac{(t-s)(T-t)}{T-s}. \end{aligned}

And indeed in [Filtration enlargement and Brownian bridge SDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4314118/filtration-enlargement-and-brownian-bridge-sde?rq=1), as you mentioned they develop an SDE with strong solution.